# mysql cursor lock in share mode

Tags: mysql, locking, cursor, share, mode

i have a question about the next cursor. hope you guys can help me out with this doubt.

```
declare var_done boolean default false;

declare var_cursor cursor for

select
tc.columnA,
tc.columnB,
tcp.columnA,
tcp.columnB

from tableA tc

inner join tableB tcp
on (tc.columnH=tcp.columnH)

where tc.columnH=paramH
and tc.columnFLG='S'
lock in share mode;

declare continue handler for not found set var_done=true;
declare exit handler for sqlexception
begin
rollback;
select 'ERROR' as 'Mensaje'
from dual;
end;

start transaction;

-- code

commit;
```

this is how my sp looks like. as you can see i'm using "lock in share mode" in the select i use for the cursor, wich i open the the "-- code" section.

my doubt is, i'm not sure if "lock in share mode" works from the cursor. will it lock tableA and tableB while the cursor is working?

thanks very much for your help.